# How to read data from a file using a class's member method in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I've created a class called Stud which contains data and member methods about students.

I would like one of the member methods, getData, to read data from a file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Stud {
  private int studentId;
  private String studentName;
  private String sex;
  private int exam1;
  private int exam2;
  private int exam3;
  private int examAverage;
  private String studentGrade;

  public void getData(Scanner inFile) {
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
      studentId = inFile.nextInt();
      studentName = inFile.next();
      sex = inFile.next();
      exam1 = inFile.nextInt();
      exam2 = inFile.nextInt();
      exam3 = inFile.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to read data from the file in the main class like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
      Stud myStud = new Stud(inFile.nextInt(), inFile.next(), inFile.next(),
                             inFile.nextInt(), inFile.nextInt(), 
                             inFile.nextInt());
    }

    inFile.close();
  }
}
```

How do I use the getData method to read in the data?

Comment: It looks to me like the Stud is simply an object representing a student?

In this case you'd probably NOT want it to have the Scanner itself, as this is something that is reading in the data - it's a nicer design personally the way you have it right now. If you wanted it to read the data then pass the Scanner reference in to the Stud class.

Comment: `I know how to read data from the file in the main class like this` that does not read from a file, it reads from your console input. Do you really want to read from a text file or from user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't read from a file but from a `stdin`. You can redirect a file to app's `stdin`, but let's stick to the nomenclature.

I'm not very fancy about your approach, but the following should fix the issue:

```
public void getData(Scanner inFile) {
    if (inFile.hasNextInt() {
      studentId = inFile.nextInt();
    } if (inFile.hasNext() {
         studentName = inFile.next();
    } if (inFile.hasNext() {
          sex = inFile.next();
    } if (inFile.hasNextInt() {
          exam1 = inFile.nextInt();
    } if (inFile.hasNextInt() {
          exam2 = inFile.nextInt();
    } if (inFile.hasNextInt() {
          exam3 = inFile.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This approach, combined with akgren_soar 's suggestion solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are just exploring constructors and methods so I shall not comment on your programming style

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            Stud myStud = new Stud();
            myStud.getData(inFile);
        }

        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

Question: Why only the last record prints? Its because of the redundant loop in `getData()`

```
public void getData(Scanner inFile) {
    studentId = inFile.nextInt();
    studentName = inFile.next();
    sex = inFile.next();
    exam1 = inFile.nextInt();
    exam2 = inFile.nextInt();
    exam3 = inFile.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I tried before posting the question. However, when I do this, only the last record of my file prints. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You only store a reference to one object. Make an `ArrayList` of `Stud`s and keep the references there.

Comment: @MatthewBlinstrub I have updated the solution. It should work fine now